# Is there a way to sort an Observablecollection?

Tags: vb.net, observablecollection

so i do have a small problem in hands, so i have an Observablecollection holding some items that a user can choose, depending on a setting the list can be be sorted Ascending(new items will be on the bottom of the list) or Descending(new items on top of the list). Now my problem comes when the list is getting bigger(i.e.: 20+ items) the application gets slow.

So i have a function so sort the list

```
If Globals.isSorterenSelected Then
    If Globals.SorterenValue = "Ascending" Then
       Dim l As List(Of clsOrderItems) = (From o In OrderregelsGegroepeerd).OrderBy(Function(f) f.Gang).ThenBy(Function(f) f.item).OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.hoofdartikel).ToList
       OrderregelsGegroepeerd = New ObservableCollection(Of clsOrderItems)(l)
    Else
       Dim l As List(Of clsOrderItems) = (From o In OrderregelsGegroepeerd).OrderBy(Function(f) f.Gang).ThenByDescending(Function(f) f.hoofdartikel).OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.item).ToList
       OrderregelsGegroepeerd = New ObservableCollection(Of clsOrderItems)(l)

     End If
Else
    Dim l As List(Of clsOrderItems) = (From o In OrderregelsGegroepeerd).OrderBy(Function(f) f.Gang).ThenBy(Function(f) f.item).OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.hoofdartikel).ToList
    OrderregelsGegroepeerd = New ObservableCollection(Of clsOrderItems)(l)

End If
```

Is there any other way to sort the "OrderregelsGegroepeerd " without having to re-create the entire Observablecollection?

Comment: Although in C#, the answer here may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330704/sorting-list-vs-observablecollection

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the reply, and yes indeed that was the path i was using i will Answer my own question with the solution i come up with that is working!

Answer (score 1):

```
'OrderregelsGegroepeerd = New ObservableCollection(Of clsOrderItems)(l)
 Dim NewIndex As Integer = 0
 For Each regel As clsOrderItems In l
     Dim idx As Integer = OrderregelsGegroepeerd.IndexOf(regel)
     OrderregelsGegroepeerd.Move(idx, NewIndex)
     NewIndex = NewIndex + 1
 Next
```

So that's the way i come up with, now i just have a small problem with the converter behind the new item but thats not a big deal! Thanks for the reply from keyboardP, that i actually only saw it before i figured the problem, but is still a good source of infomation.